# Wait for promise to resolve in Base View then continuing action in extended view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have created a base view that I extend, what I would like to do is animate a selector in the base and using deferreds resolve and continue with another action in the extended view but I'm not sure how to achieve this? Right now the console log in the when function logs instantly :/

**JS**

```
    var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile( $('.tmpl-example').html() ),

    initialize: function() {

    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template() );

        _.defer(function() {
            this.afterRender();
        }.bind(this));

        return this;
    },

    afterRender: function() {
        this.deferred = $.Deferred();

        this.$('.js-panel').addClass('animate');

        this.$('.js-panel').on('transitionend', function() {
            this.deferred.resolve();
        }.bind(this));


    }
});

var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    initialize: function() {    
        $.when(this.deferred).done(function() {
            console.log('now go do something???');
        });
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/jn35b8pw/

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `this.deferred` has not been defined when it is run in the ChildView.  It is basically running: `$.when(undefined).done(function() { ... });` which is why it executes immediately.

You can get the behavior you are expecting by setting up `this.deferred` in your ParentView's initialize function:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile( $('.tmpl-example').html() ),
    initialize: function() {
        this.deferred = $.Deferred();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template() );
        _.defer(function() {
            this.afterRender();
        }.bind(this));
        return this;
    },
    afterRender: function() {
        this.$('.js-panel').addClass('animate');
        this.$('.js-panel').on('transitionend', function() {
            this.deferred.resolve();
        }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

Just make sure in your ChildView's `initialize` function you are calling 'super':

```
var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        ParentView.prototype.initialize.call(this); // call super
        $.when(this.deferred).done(function() {
            console.log('now go do something???');
        });
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zspxL3bd/